# Increasing heap space in payara server

Tags: heap-memory, payara

We are using payara server with java 7. RAM size is 4GB and the server is running with 2 CPU. Nowadays we are getting heap memory space exception while trying to process file with 100 000 records. How to check and increase heap memory space in putty and web console(in JVM)?

Answer (score 4):

In the admin console go to Configurations -> server-config -> JVM Settings -> JVM Options. To increase the heap memory space change the -Xmx value to something higher. By default it is -Xmx512m, which is a heap space of 512 MB. You can increase this to 2048 MB BY changing it to -Xmx2048m.